# React: Unable to export * as something

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using the following dependencies:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "i18next": "^19.9.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.9",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

#### Issue

I am trying to export all my redux actions as:

```js
export * as actions from './actions';
```

And I am getting the following error:

```js
./src/app/redux/index.js 4:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> export * as actions from './actions';
```

I am migrating my code from react-17 (where it was working fine)

Comment: You can not currently export * as named namespaces like that. But you can use export statement like => `export {foo as actions} from './actions'`

Comment: Can you show us how your "./actions" are exported?

Comment: `export * as something` is new proposal for ECMA2021. You need to split it into separate import/export statements until the syntax is adopted. `import * as actions from ...;` and then `export { actions };`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's such syntax allowing you to `export * as obj` in JavaScript. For defining your actions, you would have to do something like this for each action:

actions.js

```js
export const myAction = () => {
  // Do stuff
};

export const myAction2 = () => {
  // Do stuff
};
```

Component.js

```js
import * as actions from "../directory/to/actions";
```

If you have a lot of actions in one file, and wish to keep them there. You could store them as an object and export that as the default, if you'd perefer that.

actions.js

```js
const actions = {
    myAction: () => {
        // Do stuff
    },
    myAction2: () => {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

export default actions;
```

Component.js

```js
import actions from "../directory/to/actions";
```

Comment: I have worked this way on 5 different projects. and clearly there is such syntax